# Why do we need to call Lua's collectgarbage() twice?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

I have encountered [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488814/does-luajit-support-gc-for-tables) [places](http://sourceforge.net/p/luabind/mailman/message/23606367/) where people call [collectgarbage()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage) **twice** to finalize all unused objects.

Why is that? Why isn't a single call enough? Why not three calls?

When I try the following code (on Lua 5.2), the object gets finalized (meaning: its `__gc` gets called) with just a single call to `collectgarbage`:

```
do
  local x = setmetatable({},{
    __gc = function() print("works") end
  })
end
collectgarbage()
os.exit()
```

Does this mean one call is enough?

Answer (score 18):

It's explained in *Programming in Lua* 3rd edition §17.6 Finalizers. In short, it's because of resurrection.

A finalizer is a function associated with an object that is called when that object is about to be collected. Lua implements finalizers with `__gc` metamethod.

The problem is, when the finalizers are called, the object must be alive in some cases. *PiL* explains it with this example:

> ```
> A = {x = "this is A"}
> B = {f = A}
> setmetatable(B, {__gc = function (o) print(o.f.x) end})
> A, B = nil
> collectgarbage() --> this is A
> ```
>
> The finalizer for `B` accesses `A`, so `A` cannot be collected before the finalization of `B`. Lua must resurrect both `B` and `A` before running that finalizer.

Resurrection is the reason of calling `collectgarbage` twice:

> Because of resurrection, objects with finalizers are collected in two phases.
>   The first time the collector detects that an object with a finalizer is not reachable, the collector resurrects the object and queues it to be finalized. Once its finalizer runs, Lua marks the object as finalized. The next time the collector detects that the object is not reachable, it deletes the object. If you want to ensure that all garbage in your program has been actually released, you must call `collectgarbage` twice; the second call will delete the objects that were finalized during the first call.

Comment: The quote "the second call will delete the objects that were finalized during the first call" (and "The next time the collector detects [...] it deletes the object") says, if I understand it correctly, that the finalizer (`__gc`) is run at the [end of the] **first** call to `collectgarbage()`. Then, the **second** call to `coollectgarbage` just frees the memory (manual: "the object memory is freed in the next garbage-collection cycle". PiL: see previous quote). My own example (the code in my question) supposedly "proves" this understanding of mine. But...

Comment: ... But my understanding must be wrong because my [second link](http://sourceforge.net/p/luabind/mailman/message/23606367/) proves it wrong (i.e., the finalizer wasn't called on first `collectgarbage`; see "I had to add one more collectgarbage() call") and the [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488814/does-luajit-support-gc-for-tables) contains a comment (by a user) saying "[calling] twice ensures all finalizers are called" (maybe that comment is wrong). So I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Ooops, I see my error. My [first link](http://sourceforge.net/p/luabind/mailman/message/23606367/) deals with lua 5.1.4, which doesn't have finalizers, so it's completely irrelevant for us. Sorry.

Comment: So, I'd appreciate a clear cut acknowledgement of my understanding: `__gc` is called on **first** call to collectgarbage(), right? If I understand wrong, how did I misinterpret the quotes? (BTW, I did read your code sample.)